# SQLDelight just generated IOS Database generated classes, but android doesn't. Kmm proyect

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, sqldelight

I was developing an Kotlin Multiplatform App, using as base, the generated Architectured by Android Studio.

My problem, comes when I try to implement the SQLDelight plugins into my app, because the plugin just generated iOS classes as you can see in the following picture:

[image]

Regarding to my code:

`build.gradle` (Proyect)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0")
        classpath(kotlin("gradle-plugin", version = Versions.kotlin))
        classpath(kotlin("serialization", version = Versions.kotlin))
        classpath("com.squareup.sqldelight:gradle-plugin:${Versions.sqldelight}")
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

plugins{
    //kotlin("android") version "${Versions.kotlin}" apply false
}
tasks.register("clean", Delete::class) {
    delete(rootProject.buildDir)
}
```

`build.gradle.app`

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.library")
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

version = "1.0"

kotlin {
    android()
    iosX64()
    iosArm64()
    //iosSimulatorArm64() sure all ios dependencies support this target

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Some description for the Shared Module"
        homepage = "Link to the Shared Module homepage"
        ios.deploymentTarget = "14.1"
        podfile = project.file("../iosApp/Podfile")
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting{
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib-common"))
                implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
                implementation(Ktor.Core.common)
                implementation(Ktor.Json.common)
                implementation(Ktor.Logging.common)
                implementation(Ktor.Serialization.common)
                implementation(SqlDelight.runtime)

            }
        }
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-common"))
                implementation(kotlin("test-annotations-common"))
                implementation(Ktor.Mock.common)
            }
        }
        val androidMain by getting{
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
                implementation(Coroutines.Core.core)
                implementation(Ktor.android)
                implementation(Ktor.Core.jvm)
                implementation(Ktor.Json.jvm)
                implementation(Ktor.Logging.jvm)
                implementation(Ktor.Logging.slf4j)
                implementation(Ktor.Mock.jvm)
                implementation(Ktor.Serialization.jvm)
                implementation(Serialization.core)
                implementation(SqlDelight.android)
            }
        }
        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test-junit"))
                implementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting
        val iosArm64Main by getting
        //val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
        val iosMain by creating {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            //iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
            dependencies {
                implementation(SqlDelight.native)
            }
        }
        val iosX64Test by getting
        val iosArm64Test by getting
        //val iosSimulatorArm64Test by getting
        val iosTest by creating {
            dependsOn(commonTest)
            iosX64Test.dependsOn(this)
            iosArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
            //iosSimulatorArm64Test.dependsOn(this)
        }
    }
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    sourceSets["main"].manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
    }
}
sqldelight {
    database("PetsDatabase") {
        packageName = "com.example.kmp_app.db"
        sourceFolders = listOf("sqldelight")
    }
}
```

Regarding the creation of Android Driver in `AndroidMain`:

```
import android.content.Context
import com.squareup.sqldelight.android.AndroidSqliteDriver
lateinit var appContext: Context

internal actual fun cache(): PetsDatabase {
  val driver = AndroidSqliteDriver(PetsDatabase.Schema, appContext, "petsDB.db")
  return PetsDatabase(driver)
}
```

Regarding the error in the repository when I try to use the generate class `Database` in `commonMain` repository is this:

[image]

Finally regarding the location of my `.sq` file in commonMain is this:

[image]

Comment: Hello, @manuel-lucas! Could you please extend the question with the information about versions of all libraries that you use? I've found a pretty similar issue here: https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight/issues/2085, where it is said that some SQLDelight version should help.

Comment: HI @Philip Dukhov, finally I found a solution, changing the directory of the .sq file, adding dataSource.cacheSource. So the tree of directories of my .sq file is <project-route>/db/dataSource/cacheSource